# How do I overlay divs in ASP.NET?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

So I have 3 tabs at the top of form they are contained in `<div>`s.
Here is the CSS:

```css
.lefttab1 {

    position: relative;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -1px 2px #CCC;
    height: 35px;
    width: 300px;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 44px;
    padding-top: 10px;


}

.midtab {
    position: relative;   
    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 2px -1px 2px #CCC;
    height: 35px;
    width: 400px;
    margin-top: 44px;
    margin-left: 259px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.righttab1 {


    border-top-right-radius: 50px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 375px;
    float: right;
    margin-top: -45px;
    padding-top: 10px;


}
```

Here is the markup:

```
<a href="/account.aspx" class="lefttab1 tabcolorGrey">
                 <asp:Label ID="lablelft" runat="server" ForeColor="#a1a1a1" text="Select A Payment Account" CssClass="tabtextLeft1"></asp:Label>
            </a>
            <div class="midtab tabcolorGrey">
                 <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" ForeColor="#a1a1a1" text="Payment Information" CssClass="tabtextLeft1"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <div class="righttab1 tabcolorPurple">
                 <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" ForeColor="#ffffff" text="Payment Confirmation" CssClass="tabtextRight1"></asp:Label>
            </div>
```

So, Lefttab1 needs to overlay midtab, and midtab should overlay righttab1.  Right now it appears that Lefttab1 is NOT overlaying midtab, but midtab is overlaying righttab1.  What can I do, I have tried manipulating the `postion:` attribute, and I have tried the `z-index`, but nothing seems to work. Any advice would be appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: Why are you using labels at all? Labels are for describing input form fields. Just use a span, anchor, etc directly as html. If the labels do describe an input you should be using AssociatedControlId http://haacked.com/archive/2007/02/15/asp.net_tip_-_use_the_label_control_correctly.aspx/

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out ... I was using the z-index in reverse, so the last overlapping element was set to 1 instead of 3, once I reversed it, and set the last element on the page lefttab1 to z-index = 3, then midtab z-index = 2, and righttab1 = 1.

Answer (score -2):

What version of the .NET framework are you using?

There's a tab control in the AJAX toolkit that'll do this for you. If you're using 3.5+ I believe it's included.

Comment: That's not an answer. It's a question/suggestion, and should be posted as comment.

Comment: .Net 4.5 ... we are Software Engineers